# laravel callback url with file_get_contents('php://input')

Tags: php, laravel

in vanilla php i would create a callbak url with just

```
 try
      {
     //response content type application/json
          header("Content-Type:application/json");
            //read incoming request
          $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
        .......
        ......
```

but in laravel i'm yet to get a clear explanation on how to achieve the same

ive tried using

```
 $postData = Request::getContent();
```

but it returns blank

Comment: Which facade are you using for Request ?

Comment: What's the purpose of this? If it's to read JSON data from the input then `request()->json("dot separated path")` works. Also `request()->all()` might work.

Comment: yes the purpose is to read json data. and im using \Illuminate\Http\Request for the requests

Answer (score 0):

If you need data in request use `(new \Illuminate\Http\Request())->all()` or use DI

```
public function someAction(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
   dd($request->all());
}
```